# Index Function with error "You've entered too many arguments for this function"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

```
=index(_70Rain,1+int((row(b4)-1/columns(_70Rain)),mod(row(b4)-1+columns(_70Rain),columns(_70Rain))+1)
```

I just followed the code given in https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1172-excel-transpose-multiple-columns-into-one-column.html, transposing multiple rows into a single column.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For education purposes, the problem is a parentheses. There is one extra, or one too few which could belong in either of two places.

The goal of the formula dictates it is one too few, and it belongs where `Lee` has placed it. The other two real possibilities were there should be one less before `ROW()` in `INDEX()`'s row parameter or there should be one more after that whole calculation.

With it as you show the formula, everything after the range is a single parameter to Excel. And since it is three unconnected pieces when seen that way, Excel has no idea how to handle it. So it tells you that, as closely as it's able (not very, you know, the old "clear as mud" saying applies here), and it puts you at a possible (to Excel) spot in the rightmost portion of the erring portion. Even though the fix takes place four feet to the left of that spot.

One useful thing to do when adapting a formula you get from someone else, especially online, is to edit it to add spaces AFTER commas and parentheses so that pieces stand out to you. THEN do your editing for addresses and such. Not only will it go faster for you, but many formulas found online to do clever things are dependent upon clever tricks and the pieces-parts those clever tricks are built out of are not always clear to the person adapting it (i.e.:  seeing it for the first time). So breaking it apart like I say can help you avoid replacing too much or too little with your required adaptations. It can be handy to have a saving throw, but even handier to not need one to begin with. (I might also mention that understanding them for future use can be destroyed if one has some little typo type error but one spends an hour on minutiae back and forth, trying to solve it at first on a whole formula basis, then on a "so many things have been changed, but I just need one more little thing and it will work" basis, and finally on a start over from the beginning and never use the technique again or even just dump it and never look back basis. Then everything's wasted.)

Without the goal of the formula, it would be hard to tell just where it belonged. I never like to "preach" about how one finds a way to understand a thing, or what works as logical presentation for someone, but since so much using Excel depends powerfully upon one's exact set-up and goals, it is always good to dive right into them at the start of a question. Then give formulas and such and tell what went wrong so far as Excel's concerned.

As I say, I hate to "preach" on such things and I'm not here. But if you look at a dozen or two questions you might notice a decent number of folks here see something not leaping out at them and comment asking (demanding) data, formulas, screenshots, artificial data, all kinds of things, even though the questioner's goal or problem is discernible with some thought. The point being, a practical point, that some of the people who'd have an answer and pretty quickly just won't if the question doesn't seem clear when they scan it. So as a practical matter, for getting an answer at all (sometimes), or getting one quickly (desirable, especially at work), quickly giving one's goal, then what is going wrong can often bring one much better happiness with the whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this formula:

```
=INDEX(_70Rain,INT((ROW(B4)-1)/COLUMNS(_70Rain)),MOD(ROW(B4)-1+COLUMNS(_70Rain),COLUMNS(_70Rain))+1)
```

[image]